# Prevent Perforce From Marking Files As Read Only

Tags: windows, version-control, perforce

How do I prevent Perforce from marking files as 'Read Only' in Windows 10? I'd like to never have to deal with it. I know that checking out files will make them no longer read only, but that is not an acceptable answer. I want to be able to pull things and NOT have to manually set everything as writeable.

Answer (score 4):

Set the `allwrite` option in your client spec.

P4V:
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Content/P4V/using.workspaces.html

P4:
https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_client.html

Once that option is set, all files created by `p4 sync` will be left writable.  Note that if you do this you probably want to get in the habit of always running `p4 reconcile` before submitting, since it's very easy otherwise to end up with stealthily unsubmitted files.

Comment: It's easy to end up with stealthily unsubmitted files with perforce even with the read-only option turned on.